# Salesforce Metadata Update tools

Tags: trigger, metadata-api, validation-rule

We are looking for a tool to reactivate Apex triggers(100), Flows(20), WF rules(50) and Validations rules (1700). During data seeding in a sandbox from PROD using a famous tool had deactivated all the above metadta (normal expected process) but when the job was aborted, the famous tool did not reactivate the triggers, validations rules, flows and wf rules. 
We have tried using sfswitch tool but its taking longer time to download the metadata and also while updating the changes getting UI error.
Please suggest any effective online tool for this if anyone has gone through this in their projects.

Note: 
We don'y use Eclipse IDE due to some reason, checking with Gearset also but looking for any other available option.

Thanks,
HRZ

Comment: Gearset will do this provided the source of the comparison (org or source control) has these metadata items `active`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Salesforce Switch works just fine for this purpose provided you carefully avoid selecting any *managed* metadata as part of your update. Accidentally selecting managed metadata will produce an error as you described. I've used it for this type of task multiple times.

Any tool will take substantial time to retrieve metadata in an organization the size of the one you are describing.

You can also complete this activity using literally any Metadata API-fluent tool by simply editing the XML metadata for your customizations and then pushing them back into your sandbox. That could be Workbench, Eclipse, Salesforce DX, the Force.com CLI, you name it.

Comment: Thanks David for the prompt response. We have done this using GearSet successfully.